# Understanding ipconfig output in Windows

Tags: ip, tcp, ipconfig

I use Windows 7 and am connected to a LAN. In `cmd` I typed `ipconfig`.

1. There were many headings reading "Tunnel adapter local area connections" (with 13/19/17   appended to it). What does this mean?
2. Also there were physical addresses like 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0...is this some kind of MAC address?

Comment: @slhck...thanks...i edited this question here...now u can take a look...other two questions are....[1](http://superuser.com/questions/372954/output-of-tcpdump) and [2](http://superuser.com/questions/372953/ips-displayed-in-nslookup-and-netstat)

Comment: on point 2. here, what was the context of the 'physical address' or does it just say; Physical Address: blah blah blah?

Comment: @CodeBlend...i have edited the physical address...these kind of physical addresses were defined under heads like tunnel  adapter connection 13/14/17/19...,tunnel  adapter isatap...

Answer (score 1):

As per the screenshot, when you have these:

- Tunnel Adapter Local Area Connection* 13
- Tunnel Adapter Local Area Connection* 17
- etc.

[Vista - Anyone know what "Tunnel Adapters" are in ipconfig?](http://www.vistax64.com/vista-networking-sharing/45101-anyone-know-what-tunnel-adapters-ipconfig.html)

Puppy Breath - **Re: Anyone know what "Tunnel Adapters" are in ipconfig?**:

> Tunneling is how you do secure (encrypted) communications across an
>   untrusted network (the Internet). Those look like
>   IPv6 tunneling. See these pages:
>
> - http://www.microsoft.com/technet/net...6/ipv6faq.mspx
> - http://www.microsoft.com/technet/net...6/ipv6faq.mspx
>
> or search for "Vista Teredo Tunneling" or something like that at MS or
>   Google.

[Teredo tunneling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling)

[ipconfig shows 'tunnel adapter' what is it?](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/forums/23/windows-vista/296695/ipconfig-shows-tunnel-adapter-what-is-it-/):

> Forum Editor - Posted August 19, 2007 at 12:36PM
>
> it's pretty dry and complicated, and a full explanation would have us
>   both asleep in minutes.
>
> Suffice it to say that it's concerned with a Windows networking
>   component called IPv6, which handles network addressing.

[You could disable IPv6 if you don't want these to display](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/network/ipv6/ipv6faq.mspx)

---

[How Do I Find the MAC Address (Physical Address) of My PC?](http://www.dowling.edu/mydowling/tech/macaddress.html)

> Lots of information will be displayed, but what you need is in the
>   Ethernet Adapter Local Area Connection section. Write down the
>   Physical Address that looks like "0A-B1-C2-D3-E4-F5". This is the "MAC
>   Address."
>
> Your MAC Address (Physical Address) almost always starts with a zero.
>   If you're writing down a number that does not start with "0" you've
>   probably got the wrong number.

[Standard Group MAC Addresses: A Tutorial Guide](http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/tut/macgrp.pdf)

I think the first two *bits* bar the odd exception are 00, so I am not sure why yours wouldn't:

> This document implies that for an individually, globally assigned MAC
>   address the first two *bits* will be zero. The first two hexadecimal
>   digits of the MAC address (i.e. '08') represent the first eight *bits*
>   and, in your case, the first two bits are, infact, zero.

Comment: @CodeBlend...my mac address doesn't start with 0

Comment: @CodeBlend...here is the [screen shot](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=24lppg2&s=5)

Comment: Not sure about a MAC address that doesn't start with a 0 hmm =S

Comment: Your answer doesn't really read easily. It's a collection of links. Would you mind adding a bit of text actually explaining?

Comment: @CodeBlend...i understood answer to first question...have u answered my second question(i cant make out)?

Comment: @avinash I don't know what a MAC Address starting with a 0 means, I just gave you all the resources relating to MAC Addresses so you could maybe establish if what you are looking at is a true MAC Address or not