# Why is my IP displayed in nslookup and netstat different?

Tags: windows, linux, dns, ip

i am connected to the internet through a LAN. When I see my IP in Windows 7 when using `netstat -a`, my IP is `172.19...`, but when I used Linux (Ubuntu), for just checking a host name by `nslookup`, there was my server address which was `192.168...`.

Why is my IP different in `netstat` and `nslookup`?

Comment: @iglvzx...i respect your zest to close a duplicate question(nice work )...but i don't think this question is anywhere near the question you suggested...if you look at both of my ip addresses,they are both private(172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255 and 192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255 )...so there is no question of any IP being of the router...plz comment and clear my doubt as answers have been disabled

Comment: Ah. My bad. Thanks for clarifying... Are Windows and Ubuntu on the same machine? Dual-boot? Virtualized? It is possible that Ubuntu is set up to use [NAT](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).

Comment: Also, note that `nslookup` is for querying the DNS servers.

Answer (score 0):

VMs use private internal addressing and NAT to function, mapping these to the actual underlying hardware address of the host machine. This is normal, expected behavior of a virtualized instance.

Comment: @gmari...so in actuality the nat of lan provides me which ip?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @avinash: each operating system (VM host Windows and VM guest Linux) is on a separate LAN, one LAN is virtual. If so configured, NAT translates the guest's IP-address to that of the host for communicating through the physical LAN.